# Error when downloading package using git+ssh

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, github, package

I am working on creating a private package repository for my company and am trying to download the package from Github. I believe the package should compile, as I have uploaded this as a test function to PyPI.

The error I get is: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: setup.py` I am cloning the repo back into the exact same environment in which the function was created - what could be wrong?

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tokenize.py", line 454, in open
    buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'C:\\Users\\ALLENB~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-07k46aoa-build\\setup.py'
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
C:\Users\ALLENB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-07k46aoa-build\setup.py
```

Comment: What directory are you running `setup.py` from? It is not supposed to be part of your actual python location. It comes with the packages!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setup.py` is not part of the Python/Anaconda 3 installation location!

It's included with the package that you wish to install. Change directories to the location of the source that you download it with `pip install` (or with: `py -m pip install`) and then run the `setup.py` file.

---

**EDIT:**

Add `#subdirectory=folder_name` to your code.

Comment: This was the exact right answer. I did not have `setup.py` in the main repo folder. I did have it in a subfolder. When I added `#subdirectory=folder_name` to the code, it worked.

Comment: Done - since I'm new to SO, you might not see my +1 (but it's there) :)